# Cannot add matrices more than 20 times in loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, factorial

I'm trying to create a sum of 2x2 matrices in a for loop, but when I loop the summation more than 21 times (when my n > 20, as shown below) it gives me the following error message:

> TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

This is my code:

```
k = 2
n = 21

A2 = np.matrix('0.5 -0.5; 0.5 0.5')
SumA2 = np.zeros((k,k))

for i in range(0, n+1):
    SumA2 += np.linalg.matrix_power(A2, i)/np.math.factorial(i)

print(A2)
print("\n", SumA2)
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the factorial becoming too big, but should that really be an issue? In Matlab I can loop it 1000 times without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 21, it switches the array type to object:

```
In [776]: np.linalg.matrix_power(A2,20)/np.math.factorial(20)
Out[776]: 
matrix([[-4.01398205e-22,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 0.00000000e+00, -4.01398205e-22]])
In [777]: np.linalg.matrix_power(A2,21)/np.math.factorial(21)
Out[777]: 
matrix([[-9.557100128609015e-24, 9.557100128609015e-24],
        [-9.557100128609015e-24, -9.557100128609015e-24]], dtype=object)
```

more specifically, it's the `factorial` that's switched:

```
In [778]: np.array(np.math.factorial(20))
Out[778]: array(2432902008176640000)
In [779]: np.array(np.math.factorial(21))
Out[779]: array(51090942171709440000, dtype=object)
```

Python3 is using integers for the `factorial`.  Those can be any length.  But at this point the value becomes too large to represent with `np.int64`.  So it switches to using an object dtype array that holds the long Python integer.  That switch propagates to the `power` calculation.

The error arises when it tries to convert this array to a dtype compatible with `SumA2`.

```
In [782]: SumA2 = np.zeros((k,k))
In [783]: SumA2 += Out[777]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-783-53cbd27f9514> in <module>()
----> 1 SumA2 += Out[777]

TypeError: ufunc 'add' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
In [784]: SumA2 = np.zeros((k,k), object)
In [785]: SumA2 += Out[777]
In [786]: SumA2
Out[786]: 
array([[-9.557100128609015e-24, 9.557100128609015e-24],
       [-9.557100128609015e-24, -9.557100128609015e-24]], dtype=object)
```

At 170 it starts having problems converting integer to float

Do a `1/factorial(...)` first seems to help.  And changing the dtype of `A2` to a higher precision float may help:

```
In [812]: np.linalg.matrix_power(A2.astype('float128'),171)*(1/np.math.factorial(171))
Out[812]: 
matrix([[-1.04145922e-335, -1.04145922e-335],
        [ 1.04145922e-335, -1.04145922e-335]], dtype=float128)
```

With a 2x2 matrix, this really doesn't make special use of `numpy`.  The repeated power could almost as easily be calculated with lists and 'raw' Python numbers.  But even those aren't designed for infinite precision math.  Integers can be long, but I don't think Python floats are that flexible.

Comment: Changing the initial dtype of `SumA2` to object seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it up to n=170. I'll have a look on how to go from there to larger numbers.

Comment: Yes, you start hitting integer to float conversion issues.  `numpy` and Python aren't designed for infinite precision math.